# How applications like MS Teams update

Tags: angular, windows, electron, microsoft-teams, desktop-application

We had a teams issue today morning and it was fixed within a few hours. One thing I noticed is that the bug in the application (MS Teams) was fixed while it was running. Some of us had to restart but for most of us did not need a restart.

My question is, how does something like that happen? For example, in Windows Forms/WPF application, my understanding is you cannot change the program files (the exe and etc) while it is running without restarting the application and running some sort of a helper application to do the file swapping. I know that MS Teams has not been built using .NET technology stack, but I'm just curious how they work around the issue and when the updates are actually applied.

I am not really familiar with electron and this could be normal for an electron app built using JavaScript. Does anyone have an explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The desktop client updates itself automatically. Teams checks for updates every few hours behind the scenes, downloads it, and then waits for the computer to be idle before silently installing the update.

Refrence docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/teams-client-update